# RadioButtons behavior with nested GroupBoxes

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, groupbox

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a GroupBox as a purely aesthetic object. Simply put, I have a large group box with many smaller group boxes inside it. They all have radio buttons in them. I want that the user can activate only one radio button among them all.

Right now, after building the wanted user interface, I have an unwanted behavior, i.e. the radio buttons are ruled by the inner most group boxes, so the user can activate one in each small group boxes.

I'm following a guideline so I don't want to modify the way the user interface is constructed. I'm not sure if nesting group boxes makes sense, but I need to follow that path. Is there an explicit property that tell which object rules a given radiobutton?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: unfortunately for that layout, that is how RBs work.  They will work that way with any container control (like a panel with no border so you cant see the container).  You might consider whether RBS are the right control.  Many set of 2 (On/Off) can be replaced with a checkbox. sets of more than 3 can make better use of space with a combo box.  You could also use a multi-select Listbox or checkedlistbox

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to respect the way the UI is constructed. I was looking for a simple solution, I think I will have to turn all radio buttons off with custom code except the one just pressed.

Comment: it sounds like it is a BAD UI if it is using group boxes as decorations, and spreading RBs representing a logical group into subgroups.  You are going to have a chore with the code, because you will also have to fight the natural behavior to act like they are supposed to.

Comment: @Pico Just set `AutoCheck` to `False` and do it programmatically.

Comment: You can do this; create a method that loops through all group boxes and grab the radiobuttons and toggle them, it's do able I've done it many times.

Comment: @Plutonix The code wasn't a chore I didn't think, I thought it was easy in my opinion. TESTED and works great.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well since I seen no answers being submitted I thought I would...

Also your individual events for your radio buttons are still individual and you can make changes off them as well so your not compromizing every radio button.

**UPDATE: You can have nested groupboxes in a group box OR have groupboxes alone and you can toggle this behavior if you want . . .**

```
 Public Class TestRadioButtons
 Private blnIsGroupBoxInGroupBox As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form2_Disposed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
    RemoveHandlers()
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    blnIsGroupBoxInGroupBox = False

    AddHandlers()


    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
            For Each rB As RadioButton In ctrl.Controls
                rB.AutoCheck = True
            Next
        End If
    Next

    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
            For Each rB As RadioButton In ctrl.Controls
                rB.Checked = False
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub PerformCheck(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Select Case blnIsGroupBoxInGroupBox

        Case True
            For Each cntl As Control In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf (cntl) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
                    For Each con As Windows.Forms.GroupBox In cntl.Controls
                        For Each rB As RadioButton In con.Controls
                            If rB.Name.ToString = sender.name.ToString Then
                                If rB.Checked Then
                                    For Each cont As Control In Me.Controls
                                        If TypeOf (cont) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
                                            For Each gBox As Windows.Forms.GroupBox In cont.Controls
                                                For Each rButton As RadioButton In gBox.Controls
                                                    If Not rButton.Name.Equals(sender.Name.ToString) Then
                                                        rButton.Checked = False
                                                    End If
                                                Next
                                            Next
                                        End If
                                    Next
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Case Else
            For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
                    For Each rB As RadioButton In ctrl.Controls
                        If rB.Name = sender.Name.ToString Then
                            If rB.Checked Then
                                For Each con As Control In Me.Controls
                                    If TypeOf (con) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
                                        For Each rButton As RadioButton In con.Controls
                                            If Not rButton.Name.Equals(sender.Name.ToString) Then
                                                rButton.Checked = False
                                            End If
                                        Next
                                    End If
                                Next
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub AddHandlers()

    Select Case blnIsGroupBoxInGroupBox

        Case True
            For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
                    For Each con As Windows.Forms.GroupBox In ctrl.Controls
                        For Each rB As RadioButton In con.Controls
                            AddHandler rB.CheckedChanged, AddressOf PerformCheck
                        Next
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Case Else
            For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
                    For Each rB As RadioButton In ctrl.Controls
                        AddHandler rB.CheckedChanged, AddressOf PerformCheck
                    Next
                End If
            Next

    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub RemoveHandlers()
    If Me IsNot Nothing Then
        Select Case blnIsGroupBoxInGroupBox

            Case True
                For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
                    If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
                        For Each con As Windows.Forms.GroupBox In ctrl.Controls
                            For Each rB As RadioButton In con.Controls
                                RemoveHandler rB.CheckedChanged, AddressOf PerformCheck
                            Next
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            Case Else
                For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
                    If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Windows.Forms.GroupBox Then
                        For Each rB As RadioButton In ctrl.Controls
                            RemoveHandler rB.CheckedChanged, AddressOf PerformCheck
                        Next
                    End If
                Next

        End Select
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please see UPDATE, now you can have groupboxes inside of a groupbox OR groupboxes alone and this still works; its all toggled with a boolean. I am sure you will find this to be great for what you want :) Let me know how it works out for you. THIS IS TRIED AND TESTED FOR BOTH CASES.